# Access child entity property from string - Twig / Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I access child entity property value in `twig`. Example :

This is wokring :

```
{% for entity in array %}
    {{ entity.child.child.prop1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

I wont to pass s string as param to get the same thing :

```
{% for entity in array %}
    {{ attribute(entity, "child.child.prop1") }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I get error :

> Method "child.child.prop1" for object "CustomBundle\Entity\Entity1"
>   does not exist...

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why do you even want to do that ?

Comment: I think you want https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/1296 ?

Comment: Excerpt of that link: you must do `attribute(attribute(discussion, 'child'), 'prop1')`, because `{{ attribute(entity, "child.child.prop1") }} === $entity['child.child.prop1']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [custom twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) with a function that uses the [PropertyAccess component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html) of symfony to retrieve the value. An example extension implementation can be Like:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class PropertyAccessorExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /** @var  PropertyAccess */
    protected $accessor;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getAttribute', array($this, 'getAttribute'))
        );
    }

    public function getAttribute($entity, $property) {
        return $this->accessor->getValue($entity, $property);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     *
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'property_accessor_extension';
    }
}
```

After [registering this extension as service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service), you can then call

```
{% for entity in array %}
    {{ getAttribute(entity, "child.child.prop1") }}
{% endfor %}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks I was planning to do something like that :)